# Bootstrap for social network website

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, social-networking, restrictions

Is there any restrictions or something bad of using bootstrap if you are building a social network website?

Maybe the question is stupid but I still need to know is there any restrictions of using bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

No Problem at all. [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE) is the MIT license too